# Find the number of interior points of this subspace of $l^2$.

Tags: proof-verification, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces, inner-products, lp-spaces

> Consider the Hilbert Space $l^2$.
>
> Let $S=\{(x_1,x_2,\cdot\cdot\cdot)\in l^2:\sum\dfrac{x_n}{n}=0\}$.
>
> Then find the number of interior points of $S$.

Let $(x_1,x_2,\cdot,\cdot,x_n\cdot,\cdot)\in S^\circ$. Then we must have for some $r>0$ such that $(x_1,x_2,\cdot,\cdot,x_n\cdot,\cdot)+r\in S$ where $r=(r_1,r_2,\cdot,\cdot r_n,\cdot \cdot )$

But then $\sum \dfrac{(x_n+r_n)}{n}=\sum (\dfrac{x_n}{n}+\dfrac{r_n}{n})=\sum\dfrac{r_n}{n}$

Since $r>0\implies r_i>0 $ for at least one $i\implies \dfrac{r_i}{i}\neq 0\implies \sum \dfrac{r_i}{i}\neq 0$

Thus $S^\circ =\emptyset$

Is my answer correct? Please verify

Comment: See also [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/148850).

Comment: So I can assume my answer is correct @MartinSleziak

Comment: The fact that interior of $S$ is empty is certainly correct. But that does not mean that the proof is correct too.

Comment: How can I prove it if it's not correct one @MartinSleziak

Comment: What I am missing in your proof is an explanation why such $r$ exists. (It is not very difficult, but I think adding one sentence explaining this could make the proof a bit clearer.

Comment: And perhaps you might try to prove more general result instead. It often happens that proof of a more general result can be simpler (clearer, bring more insight) than proof of a special case. (The it would only remain to show that $S$ is a proper subspace of $\ell_2$.)

Comment: My point is :such a $r>0$ exists because we can always find an open ball of some radius say $r$ such the ball with centre $x=(x_1,x_2..) $ will lie in $S$ .

Comment: I am having problem finding an example to show proper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in comments a more general result is true: [Every proper subspace of a normed vector space has empty interior](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/148850).

Perhaps you might try to prove more general result. It often happens that proof of a more general result can be simpler (clearer, bring more insight) than proof of a special case.

After showing this result it only remains to show that $S$ is a proper subspace of $\ell_2$. To see this, just notice that $(1,0,0,\dots)\notin S$ (and this sequence belongs to $\ell_2$).

---

The only place in your proof (link to the [current revision](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1482627/2)) which I think should deserve a bit more detailed explanation is this:

> Then we must have for some $r>0$ such that $(x_1,x_2,\cdot,\cdot,x_n\cdot,\cdot)+r\in S$.

To explain why such $r$ exists we can simply take some $y$ such that $y\in \ell_2$ and $y>0$. (For example, $y_n=\frac1n$.)

If $x$ is an interior point, then there is an open ball $B(x,\varepsilon)\subseteq S$ for some $\varepsilon>0$. We simply take $r:=\frac\varepsilon2 \cdot r$.

Notice that the same argument would work with any $r\in \ell_2\setminus S$. (I.e.,  you do not necessarily need $r_i>0$ for each $i$. Although such element clearly does not belong to $S$.)

---

Some stylistic advice (although this might be matter of taste, so maybe not everybody will agree): I consider the notation $x+r$ somewhat better. (Using similar symbols for similar objects.) So you could write at the beginning: "Let $x=(x_1,x_2,\cdot,\cdot,x_n\cdot,\cdot)\in S^\circ$" and then use simply the variable $x$ to denote this sequence.

Also you should not use the same symbol for two various things as you did in [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1482627/find-the-number-of-interior-points-of-s?noredirect=1#comment3020100_1482627) where you have both sequence $r$ and radius $r$.

And perhaps, since quite often the letter $r$ is used for radius, you could have used a different letter instead of $r$ for the element of $\ell_2\setminus S$. (I guess this was the reason for two different $r$'s in the comment I linked to.)