# Check $S = \{ A \in \mathbb M_n(\mathbb R) : \mathrm{tr}(A) = 0 \}$ is nowhere dense or Dense in $\mathbb M_n(\mathbb R)$

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

I know that $\mathbb M_n(\mathbb R) $ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^{n^2}$ and also I know that all the norms on $\mathbb R^{n^2}$ are equivalent. I am using this norm $$\|A\| = \max\{|a_{ij}| : 1 \leq i , j \leq n \}. $$

Any  matrix $B \in \mathbb M_n(\mathbb R)$ any open ball $S_r (B)$ centered at $B$ whose radius is $r > 0$. Let $b_{ij} = \|B\|$, then define the matrix A such that $a_{11} = b_{ij}$ and $a_{nn} = -b_{ij}$ and other element are zero. Thus $A \in S_r(B)$

Thus $S$ is dense in $\mathbb M_n(\mathbb R)$

But answer is $S$ is nowhere dense.

Comment: The set $S$ is closed, because the trace map is continuous.

Comment: Think of the similar case $\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid x+y+z = 0\}$. This is a plane. Does is make sense for this to be dense in $\mathbb{R}^3$? I also don’t understand how $B$ is supposed to be defined.

Comment: @ Jendrik : $B$ is any arbitrary matrix , i  have dined a matrix $B$.

Comment: Now, i got my mistake  and lot of thanks for the prompt reply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $A$ such that $\operatorname*{tr}{(A)}=0$ for every $c>0$, consider $A_c=(b_{ij}): b_{11}=a_{11}+c/2$ and $b_{ij}=a_{ij}$ otherwise, $\operatorname*{tr}{(B)}\neq 0$ and $\lVert A-B\rVert<c$

Answer (score 2):

Note that $S$ is a proper, linear subspace of the vector space $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ and as such [must be have empty interior](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148850/every-proper-subspace-of-a-normed-vector-space-has-empty-interior). Since the trace is continuous (as every linear functional on a finite-dimensional vector space), $S$ must be closed being the preimage of $\{0\}$.