# In a proper infinite dimensional subspace of a infinite dimensional space, are all points boundary points?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

In a proper infinite-dimensional subspace of an infinite-dimensional space, are all points boundary points? (Assume we are working with a normed Banach space).

So this is intuitively true for finite-dimensional space like $R^3$ where all planes and lines do not contain any open sets, so in fact, every point is also a boundary point. But is this true in the infinite-dimensional case where the subspace is also infinite-dimensional?

Comment: No proper subspace of a normed linear space has any interior points, so all points are boundary points.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Every proper subspace of a normed vector space has empty interior](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148850/every-proper-subspace-of-a-normed-vector-space-has-empty-interior)